# accessing perl scalar variables in ()

Tags: perl

```
$a=10 
print "$a";
print "${a}";
print "$(a)";
```

`print "$a";` and  `print "${a}";`  work exactly same way, looks like both syntax are supported in perl to print scalar variables, but  `print "$(a)";` prints strange values , Want to undersand what happens when  `print "$(a)";`

Comment: On my 5.24.1 `print $(a)` is a syntax error.

Comment: ... also a syntax error on my 5.6.2

Comment: Edited in double quotes to salvage this question

Comment: Why would you wrap a variable name in arbitrary punctuation characters and expect that to work? Why `$(a)` instead of `$[a]` or `$<a>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`$(`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#$REAL_GROUP_ID) is a valid scalar in Perl. It contains the space-separated list of group ids that the current user belongs to.

So `print "$(a)"` is equivalent to `print $( . "a)"` and you can expect output like

```
perl -e 'print "$(a)"'
100 100 14677a)
```

Comment: thanks, and why do print "$a";  and print "${a}"; work the same way,  is it that both the syntax types are supported in perl or there is any other logical reason ?

Comment: `${...}` is necessary because sometimes the sigil needs to be applied to a complicated expression (`${$foo->{bar}[42]}`). The simpler `$var` syntax is necessary because if Perl programmers had to type extra braces every time they wanted to refer to a variable, Perl would have never caught on (it is bad enough that you have to keep typing `$`).

Comment: Additionally, `${...}` may be used not just to give a variable name as the `...`, but also an expression that returns a scalar-reference, which is then dereferenced with `${}`. Really, it's a good idea to read the above-referenced "perldata" page :-)

Comment: The most common use case for `${varname}` is when you interpolate and there is no separation. Example: `"${bytes_total}B available"` (functionally the same as `${bytes_total} . 'B available'`) would not work written as `"$bytes_totalB available"` because Perl would be looking for a variable `$bytes_totalB`.

Comment: @mob you are confusing `${ scalar-ref-expr }` and `${ identifier(optional index) }`; you are talking about the former, the question is about the latter.

Comment: `${...}` has many uses, but I never said `$foo->{bar}[42]` was a scalar reference and not a string.

Comment: @mob if it is a string it is a symbolic scalar reference